# creating a loop to subset data and merge spatial data maps to create gif

Tags: r, loops, subset, gif, spatial

Hej everyone

Can anybody help me in doing a loop
for the following codes below? I basically make a dynamic mac/gif by creating new maps as a merge from Excel data and a shapefile for each year and then merge all maps together as a gif. All of this works alrady but I wonder if the code could be done via loop functions. However, I really do not know anything about them and can't figure it out

Number 1: subsetting data

```
summerhouses2007<-summerhouseprices[,c("Kommune",'2007')] #07
summerhouses2008<-summerhouseprices[,c("Kommune",'2008')] #08
summerhouses2009<-summerhouseprices[,c("Kommune",'2009')] #09
summerhouses2010<-summerhouseprices[,c("Kommune",'2010')] #10
summerhouses2011<-summerhouseprices[,c("Kommune",'2011')] #11
summerhouses2012<-summerhouseprices[,c("Kommune",'2012')] #12
summerhouses2013<-summerhouseprices[,c("Kommune",'2013')] #13
summerhouses2014<-summerhouseprices[,c("Kommune",'2014')] #14
summerhouses2015<-summerhouseprices[,c("Kommune",'2015')] #15
summerhouses2016<-summerhouseprices[,c("Kommune",'2016')] #16
summerhouses2017<-summerhouseprices[,c("Kommune",'2017')] #17
summerhouses2018<-summerhouseprices[,c("Kommune",'2018')] #18
summerhouses2019<-summerhouseprices[,c("Kommune",'2019')] #19
```

Number 2: creating, saving and merging maps as gif

```
####checking the summerhouse prices for 2007+ structure######
dim(summerhouses2007)
str(summerhouses2007$Kommune)
str(summerhouses2007$`2007`)
###so we know the "Kommune" variable - character; "2007" variable - numeric###

####merging excel data with shapefile map over municipalities####
kommune$KOMNAVN<-gsub(" Kommune","",kommune$KOMNAVN)
Municipality07<-merge(kommune, summerhouses2007, 
                    by.x=c("KOMNAVN"), by.y=c("Kommune"),all=FALSE)

####checking######
head(Municipality$`2007`)

#### making price intervals#####
p_intervals <- classIntervals(Municipality07$'2007', 5, style="fixed", 
                              fixedBreaks=c(0,1,10000,20000,30000,40000))

####choosing colors according to intervals ####
p_Colours <- findColours(p_intervals,sequential_hcl(5, palette="Reds2"))

####################################################################
### but here we just save them as png files in to the saving path###
###save the 2007.png file########
png(filename="2007.png")
plot(sea,col="cadetblue3")
plot(kommune, col= "beige",add=TRUE)
plot(Municipality, axes=TRUE, col=p_Colours, add=TRUE)

####Adding legend #####
legend("topright", 
       fill = attr(p_Colours, "palette"), 
       border="black", 
       legend=gsub(",", " - ", names(attr(p_Colours, "table"))), 
       bg ="white",
       title="Summerhouse prices 2007") 

##### saving the map  #######
dev.off()
```

Everything is repeated for 2007 up until 2020.

Cheers :)

Comment: Hi @Lily22, did you figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

If you have learned to write all that code in your question, you are certainly able to learn how to use for-loops. You can do it!

I'd recommend just experimenting with a simple loop to figure out what's going on. For example, try looping over the elements in a vector using the elements themselves.

```
fruits <- c("apple", "peach", "pear")

for(fruit in fruits){
  print(fruit)
}
```

You can also use their index.

```
fruits <- c("apple", "peach", "pear")

# Return second element in vector
fruits[2]

for(i in 1:length(fruits)){
  print(fruits[i])
}
```

Here's how you might read your data, year at a time. I'd imagine that you probably want all your code to operate within each iteration of the loop.

```
years <- 2007:2019

for(year in years){
  house <- summerhouseprices[,c("Kommune", year)]
}
```

More on loops here: https://www.r-bloggers.com/2015/12/how-to-write-the-first-for-loop-in-r/